How to propagate the wavefunction of a photon in single slit diffraction?
During my undergrad, I remember writing a simulation in which the diffraction patterns which emerge from light passing through a single slit were calculated.
This was done, basically, by calculating the resultant intensity of light at each point on the background screen by integrating the decayed amplitude multiplied by the phase of each wave over the entire slit (quite computationally heavy).
Clearly, though, this was a classical approach to the problem. However, I assume it must be possible to perform a full quantum-mechanical treatment of the setup, whereby the wavefunction of a photon within the slit is (presumably) a top-hat function, and its momentum, therefore, is the Fourier transform of this, which would be something like $\propto \text{sinc}(x)$.
Thus, my question is: if you have $\Psi(x, 0)$ (the position-basis wavefunction of the photon at time $0$, within the slit), how do you propagate it and obtain its wavefunction at some time $t$, $\Psi(x, t)$? Would this account for interference?

The calculations that one performs to get the diffraction pattern on a screen behind a single slit for the classical field and for single-photon is exactly the same. It is only the interpretation of what you get that is different. For the classical field the diffraction pattern represents an intensity distribution. For the single-photon, it is a probability distribution. The reason why it is the same calculation is because nature is just nature; it doesn't care whether we see it as a classical process or a quantum process; nature just follows the laws of nature. The calculation need not be computationally heavy. If the screen is in the far field then one can use Fraunhofer diffraction which is just Fourier transform.

Thank you very much for your answer. So, you're saying that, in this case, the classical and quantum-mechanical treatments of the problem end up resulting in identical diffraction patterns on the screen? Does this hold even when the size of the slit is far smaller than the wavelength of light?

When the size of the slit is smaller than the wavelength then light cannot propagate through it. You'll get some near field called an evanescent field, but you won't see any far-field diffraction pattern, neither in terms of a classical field nor in terms of photons.

@GregorHartlWatters We can also say the probability distribution represents an intensity pattern for many photons.

@PhysicsDave thanks a lot, that makes sense. Since the probability distribution on the screen represents the probability density of a photon hitting at any one spot, as you send more and more photons through the slit, the intensity pattern observed should match the probability distribution exactly in the limit of infinite photons.

@GregorHartlWatters to understand photon interference you can search my answers on this site .....

Feynman path integral is a solution, take many paths from the source to many equally spaced points in the slit to a single point on the screen. Calculate path length, calculate phase and hence amplitude at the screen, sum them and square it ...... repeat for all points on the screen. The result is called a probability distribution.  (You can add decayed amplitude as well, 1/r^2).
The result you find is that the maximums occur where the straight line paths (source to screen) from each set are an integer multiple of of the wavelength.  You can conclude that the EM field is resonant .... photons like to travel in full wavelengths .... identical result to Huygens principle.  The difference being Feynman assumes a field is acting on the energy transmission (i.e. photon) where as the Huygens principle is based on photons cancelling each other (which is a violation of conservation of energy).
