Connection Between Quantum Phase Shift Gate and Phase Shift in Oscillating Electric Field
I'm trying to model a Mach-Zehnder interferometer. The linear algebraic description of the phase shift matrix $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\phi}\end{pmatrix}$ makes sense to me to achieve its desired result.
However, I don't understand how this phase shift of $\phi$ relates to the phase shift in the wave-representation of a light beam, as $\vec{E} = E\sin(wt + \delta)$. How do you apply this phase shift? When I apply this phase shift to the photons in one beam of the interferometer, does it add phase exactly like $\vec{E'} = E\sin(wt + \delta+\phi)$?
To my understanding, this adds a relative phase shift between the paths. However, I'm unsure how this would physically be manifest, and I can't find another place then the oscillation of the field. If this is not the case, how can I physically realize this?
Any help would be appreciated.

You could also try Feynman's path integral approach.  Net path lengths that are not integer multiples of wavelength will have 0 probability of transmission.  For example it is possible to tune both arms of  the MZ so that no light gets through to a detector.

Thank you for the suggestion. Could you perhaps explicitly write this in an answer, it would help me a lot. Thanks

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/811072/how-to-propagate-the-wavefunction-of-a-photon-in-single-slit-diffraction/811082#811082

Also type this into the search bar for more background    "user:144747 is:answer Feynman"

This is easier to do in exponential notation, and taking into account that photons have two degrees of polarization. Then, any photon state may be written as
$$|\gamma \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} E_{0x} \\ E_{0y}e^{i\delta}\end{pmatrix}. $$
The $\delta$ term is the phase difference between the two polarization directions of the photon, $\delta = \phi_y-\phi_x $. If you apply the $P$ operator to this ket
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\phi} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E_{0x} \\ E_{0y}e^{i\delta} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}E_{0x} \\ E_{0y}e^{i(\delta+\phi)} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Adding the time dependence $\omega t$ and going back to sinusoidal form, you do get (simplifying the notation) $E' = E_0\sin(\omega t +\delta + \phi).$

Thank you. Could you please expand on how to add time dependence and get to sinusoidal form, I'm not quite familiar with this.

The time dependence is just including a $e^{i\omega t}$ term to the electric field vector. Then you have something like $e^{i(\omega t + \delta + \phi)}$. To get to sinusoidal (in this case to a cosine form, but sines and cosines are equivalent except for a phase change) you extract the real part of the complex exponential using Euler's formula. That leaves you with $\cos(\omega t + \phi +\delta)$.

Thanks, I understand now.
